У меня не подсвечиваются методы, функции в vs code
У меня два .net проекта, они оба открыты и в одном все нормально подсвечивает, а в другом нет, вот как это выглядит:


я уже все перезагружал и по отдельности открывал их, в чем дело и почему у одного работает все, а у другого нет у меня идей нет.
Я пользуюсь этими extentions:


Проверьте тип который определил VSCode для скрипта

короче, не тупите как я и не забывайте добавить csproj в sln:
dotnet sln add path/to/the/csproj

и тогда проблемы такой не будет
